# Change outerHtml code when insert image in Summernote

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

How I can custom `outerHtml` when I insert image in `Summernote`.

e.g: when I insert image I want html is `<a>` tag instead of `<img>` tag

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/240x160" />
```

or insert some data to `<img>` tag

```html
<img data-src="abc" src="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/240x160" />
```